# Cricket Live Scores :  RSS Feeds or Parsing entire HTML?

Tags: android

I want to develop an android application, that displays live cricket scores as well as some other information about matches like, venue, time, about past matches, future matches, news etc..

I got two ways for doing this application : 
 1. Parsing an HTML Page.
 2. Live Scores RSS Feeds.

I think parsing is rather inconvenient, not safer way to do this. Again i think it will be ofcourse Illegal only.

For RSS Feeds :

First this, i googled out almost two days full for finding RSS feeds, but at the end, it didnt return me anything.

Yaa, one thing i found in stackoverflow is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245174/live-cricket-scores-api-of-rss-feed).

I have gone thru that also. But the problem is it only provides live team scores of current match not the complete scorecard.

Is there anything that provides full scorecard of current match as well as past matches. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to parse RSS feeds of

> www.espncricinfo.com

.

No one will give you for free the complete detailed scorecard, venues, ball by ball comparison, graphs , run rate and other things.

If you can afford you can request the concerned authorities of www.espncricinfo.com to give you the RSS feeds for money. Else for free/educational purposes, you'll have to parse their entire html pages. They are a very authentic genuine website, and have the same layout for many years now. So your HTML parsing would work for a long time for educational purposes ...

Comment: Thanks for your Response. But parsing would be legal or not ?..Are they maintaining track of all incoming requests to their site ?

Comment: Well parsing is not illegal if you are using for non commercial purposes ... You can parse the HTML page of any website. The website owners sometimes to prevent parsing, can block a certain IP requesting pages frequently after a certain amount of time or requests... Example 5000 requests in one hour :) ... GOOGLE does it too for non commercial purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to ask, you must realize that you're already in a grey area.

I would consider what you are describing as commercial re-use, as you are effectively taking other people's hard work and making money off it. Every time they make an update to some content, you make a buck, even though they've explicitly said you can't use it in that way.

You will need to consult a lawyer for a definitive answer.

Comment: Why you are telling in both sides i dont understand. First you told that parsing is legal and now you are saying opposite. I am  not getting man...And yaa for your kind information, i have posted this question because i wanted to know whether there will be illegal issues or not.

Comment: I told you its legal if you are using it for educational purposes only. If you are aiming for commercial use, you'll have to get an affiliate account. Even when using for educational purposes, sometimes the websites do block if you are frequently requesting for a webpage. Hope now you understand.

Comment: Ok.Ok. Got it.. It would be better if i stop dreaming of developing this application. Rather than paying or getting in some illegal issues its better to stay away. Again there are lots of free applications are available for free and they have got very large number of users..

Comment: Shahab: Can i use their RSS and develop an app for Live Score update and can i upload it in google play for free??? Is that comes under illegal???

Comment: Well look at the privacy policy of the website. If it doesn't state that it can't be used for commercial purposes, then you shouldn't use it. Other wise many companies allow the use of RSS feeds for commercial purposes.